# destroy belongs_to leaves FK

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model:

```
class Merchant < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :billing_address, class_name: Address, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :other_address1, class_name: Address, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :other_address2, class_name: Address, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :other_address3, class_name: Address, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :other_address4, class_name: Address, dependent: :destroy
    ...
end
```

`Address` has no associations.

When I do this:

```
merchant.billing_address.destroy
```

In the database, the address record is gone, but `merchants.billing_address_id` keeps a bogus value.  This is mysql, so no referential integrity.

What am I doing wrong?

NOTE: I realize this might be better modeled as a `has_one` association. I might have to go there, but I prefer not to.

UPDATE: Added a little more code to show the multiple Address associations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that ActiveRecord does not support one-sided belongs_to associations, [unlike other ORMs I've worked with](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone). But you can hack it yourself like so:

```
before_save :remove_ids_for_nil_associations

def remove_ids_for_nil_associations
  self.billing_address_id = nil if is_getting_destroyed? self.billing_address
  ...
end

def is_getting_destroyed?(ref)
  ref.present? && ref.destroyed?
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want merchant.billing_address to be null after you destroy the billing address, then you need to use `:dependent => :nullify` in the Address model.

Ref http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html